# How to upload multiple files in MVC3 with a custom interface?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

There are a couple difficult parts with this one that I'm struggling with.

What I need to do is pop up the file browser window when a user clicks on text (this text would replace the functionality of the button on the usual file input) and then when they select a file, the file name (and other information I suppose) needs to be inserted into a different part of the page. The user should be able to continue adding more files by clicking on the same text and choosing another file.

Files should be able to be removed from the upload queue by clicking an icon in the area where the file name and other information was inserted. I haven't decided yet if they should be uploaded before the form submits or along with the form.

Any way, I get the feeling I'm going to have to use some sort of flash plugin because this is sounding pretty impossible with just js/jquery and MVC3.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check HTML5 FileReader API - an example can be found [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/). It even makes possible to upload files with drag'n'dropping them to specified element on page.

It's not widely supported by the browsers (specifically, IE10 should support it, but IE9 is definitely not, you can check browser compatibility [here](http://caniuse.com/filereader)) but really provides required functionality.

Comment: +1 - Google+ uses this for its profile and banner photo upload tool. It is very convenient to be able to drag an image into a box on the webpage in my browser without having to worry about flash/java/etc needing to be updated or installed or whatever. HTML5 FTW!

Comment: I actually did take a peek at that, but alas, IE screws us again. This feature will be for a commercial product and using something that isn't supported even by IE9 isn't really viable.